# How to avoid hardcoded SQLCipher encryption key (Android/PhoneGap)?

Tags: android, cordova, encryption, sqlcipher, phonegap

I want to use [SQLCipher](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter) in my first PhoneGap project to securely save sensitive user data on their devices.

According to [the example in plugin's page](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter), I have to hardcore SQLCipher's key to my codes:

```
var db = null;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'demo.db', key: 'your-password-here', location: 'default'});
});
```

But hardcoding encryption keys in the codes are not secure at all and everybody can find it by unzipping the apk file.

Here is my question: Is there any secure way to uniquely generate, save and retrieve a random key for SQLCipher per user/device in PhoneGap?

(Maybe I can make a PhoneGap plugin for that if there is a secure way in Android but not in PhoneGap itself, so any help and suggestions could be helpful)

Thanks.

Comment: Bear in mind that a generated passphrase, stored in internal storage in plaintext, is accessible by anyone who can access the database, and so this offers no additional protection. Probably there are approaches on Android 5.0+ using the keychain that avoid the stored-in-plaintext problem, but then bear in mind that backups will be useless. Give the user the option of supplying their own passphrase.

Comment: Encryption that takes place completely client-side is never secure if the keys are also client-side.  Use a user password with PBKDF2

Comment: Thank you @LukePark for your comment. Let's say I want to give the user the ability to use their own password in the app. How can I avoid asking the password every single time that they open the app? If a user opens the app 10 times per day, it's really annoying to ask them 10 times per day to enter a password. Is there a way to securely save this password for days/months/forever?

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare for your comment. But how apps like WhatsApp, Facebook and thousands other save passwords on the device? My comment above in response to to Luke Park explains it better, but SO doesn't let me to mention more than 1 user in each comment.

Comment: Consider that Facebook, WhatsApp etc. have server side authentication in the mix, whereas you don't appear to.  In these circumstances, keeping the user password safe is as difficult as keeping the initial data safe.  For adequate security, it's necessary to ask the user each time.

Comment: @LukePark so how they implemented server side authentication? AFAIK, we have to save auth key for server side authentication on the device and there is no other way, right? So we encounter the same first question again: How to securely store and retrieve this auth key on user device? I really don't want to ask the user for password, because it is possible for a user to open the app tens of times per day and that's really annoying and against UX principles. For example, I would diffidently uninstall WhatsApp if it keeps asking for my password every half an hour.

Comment: "But how apps like WhatsApp, Facebook and thousands other save passwords on the device?" -- most likely, they don't. They have an authorization token, generated server-side. The only risk to the user is if the device falls into somebody else's hands, and then at best they can get a token that the service can invalidate. "How can I avoid asking the password every single time that they open the app?" -- with PhoneGap, I have no idea. In a more traditional Android app, you would only need to ask for the passphrase when the user visits your app after its process was terminated.

Comment: As CommonsWare has stated, there **are** other ways. The most common being tokens. You can't implement this though as you don't have server interaction.  Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: @LukePark thank you.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you.